# Values fails to remove Association

Tags: list-manipulation, associations

I am toying with an anharmonic oscillator with potential

```
LJ[delta_, w_] := (w^2 - delta*w^4)
```

and I want to find the turning points for oscillations in the right well.

Thanks to fellow users of this site, I got to the point where I define this function, which returns the coordinate of a turning point, given the coordinate of its mate

```
 findZ2[z0_] := 
 First@Values@
 ToRules@Reduce[{-LJ[0.1, x] == -LJ[0.1, z0], x != z0, 
 0 <= x <= 4}, {x}]
```

I create a list

```
rangop = Subdivide[2.5, findZ2[0], 8] // Rest
{2.58278, 2.66557, 2.74835, 2.83114, 2.91392, 2.99671, 3.07949, 3.16228}
```

and try

```
Map[findZ2, rangop]
```

receining the warning

```
Values::argx: Values called with 2 arguments; 1 argument is expected.
```

and output

```
{1.82462, 1.70139, 1.56415, {x -> 1.40878}, 1.22843, 1.00982, 0.718835, 0}
```

from which the culprit, the 4th element, is clearly visible. Why Values seems not to act on the 4th only?

If I define the function (removing the `First@Values@` from the previously defined `findZ2`)

```
   findZ25[z0_] :=  ToRules@Reduce[{-LJ[0.1, x] == -LJ[0.1, z0], x != z0, 0 <= x <= 4}, {x}]
   Map[findZ25, rangop]
```

it outputs

```
{{x -> 1.82462}, {x -> 1.70139}, {x -> 1.56415}, {x -> 1.40878}, {x ->
           2.83114}, {x -> 1.22843}, {x -> 1.00982}, {x -> 0.718835}, {x -> 
           0}}
```

and everything seems in order. Now I issue

```
 Values[%]
```

and I get

```
{{1.82462}, {1.70139}, {1.56415}, {1.40878}, {2.83114}, {1.22843}, 
       {1.00982}, {0.718835}, {0}}
```

as expected, it removes all the associations. As a matter of fact, I am using this definition as a workaround, that is

```
 Flatten@Values@Map[findZ25, rangop]
```

does what I wanted in the first place, I get a list of turning point coordinates, related to their mates' coordinates in the list rangop.

Still, I would love to understand, why is it failing for the 4th element when the function findZ2 is used, that is when the Map command is issues at the end

```
Map[findZ2, rangop]
```

after the associations should have been removed?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's explore this step by step:

```
findZ2 /@ rangop
(* {1.93649, 1.82462, 1.70139, 1.56415, {x -> 2.83114}[
  1.40878], 1.22843, 1.00982, 0.718835, 0} *)

findZ2[rangop[[5]]]
(* {x -> 2.83114}[1.40878] *)
```

So the problem is not with the `Map`, but with how `findZ2` works with a particular value.

When we unroll the definition of `findZ2`, we see what the problem is:

```
With[{z0 = 2.8311388300841895`}, 
 Reduce[{-LJ[0.1, x] == -LJ[0.1, z0], x != z0, 0 <= x <= 4}, {x}]]
(* x == 1.40878 || x == 2.83114 *)

ToRules[%]
(* Sequence[{x -> 1.40878}, {x -> 2.83114}] *)

Values[%]
(* {{x -> 2.83114}[1.40878]} *)
```

When you apply `Values` to a `Sequence`, what is effectively called is (remember, `Sequence` is not a list and is spliced automatically into any function):

```
Values[{x -> 2.83114}, {x -> 2.83114}]
```

and here is how Values behaves where it is supplied with a *second* argument:

> `Values[expr,h]` gives a list of values in `expr`, wrapping each of them with head `h` before evaluation.

I hope that helps!

**Update**. If you want to make `findZ2` robust to finding more than one value, you can do something like

```
findZ2[z0_] := First@Cases[
   Reduce[{-LJ[0.1, x] == -LJ[0.1, z0], x != z0, 0 <= x <= 4}, {x}],
   _?NumberQ,
   Infinity]

findZ2 /@ rangop
(* {1.93649, 1.82462, 1.70139, 1.56415, 1.40878, 1.22843, 1.00982, \
0.718835, 0} *)
```

**Update 2**. `Values` was updated in v12.0 (I suspect to accept the second argument, but can't tell for sure), so it should simply fail in the previous versions when supplied with two arguments instead of one.

Comment: that is great thanks,  but first things first, how do you get the output between (*    *) after the first command? The 4th element is given as {x -> 2.83114}[
  1.40878]. Secondly, why would this happen only for that particular value? When I apply a different order, everything works well, including that specific value. If you could expand a bit, it would be really instructive.

Comment: 1) You used `// Rest` when you assigned `rangop`, so your list became 1 element shorter. 2) For all the other values, `Reduce` returns a single solution; but for this one, it returns 2. That's why your code works in the former but not in the latter case.

Comment: Note that when you were applying your redefined `findZ25` function, the resulting list had 9 elements, despite the original list your were mapping over had only 8. That's because the sequence returned by `ToRules@Reduce` was spliced into resulting list. Try `List[1, 2, Sequence[3, 4], 5]` and see what happens.

Comment: I see, that explains almost everything. But how can ´With[{z0 = 2.8311388300841895´}, 
 Reduce[{-LJ[0.1, x] == -LJ[0.1, z0], x != z0, 0 <= x <= 4}, {x}]]
(* x == 1.40878 || x == 2.83114 *)´, it means the ´x != z0´ is not working for one specific element, that seems weird.

Comment: You use real (not exact) coefficients, e.g. 0.1, so `Reduce` is using numerical methods. And we all know the dangers of comparing machine floats for equality, right?

Comment: we all know, right..thanks a ton, most useful